# how to match contents NOT include a string

Tags: php, regex

the content is like this

> some content and some 123 %b1% and also some content %b2% %b3%

and I want to match contents except %b1% or %b2% ...

I tried

```
([^(?:%b\d+%)]+)
```

but digtal "123" will not be included.

how to matched the contents which NOT include "%b\d+" ?

thanks.

Comment: You can do a partial match. It might be better if you explained what the final goal of that is, not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how it's done in PHP:

```
$str = "some content and some 123 %b1% and also some content %b2% %b3%";
$pattern = '/(?:^|(?!%b\d+%))(.*?)(?:%b\d+%|$)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
$match = implode($matches[0]);
```

If not, I'd be glad to hear what I'm doing wrong.  In any case, I know the Ruby solution below works.

---

Original answer:

I wish I knew PHP better, but I'm sure it would be easy enough to figure out how to convert this Ruby code to PHP:

```
str = "some content and some 123 %b1% and also some content %b2% %b3%"
match = str.scan(/(?:^|(?!%b\d+%))(.*?)(?:%b\d+%|$)/).join
```

`match` then contains:

```
"some content and some 123  and also some content  "
```

The idea is to scan for all the matches of that regex, `/(?:^|(?!%b\d+%))(.*?)(?:%b\d+%|$)/`, and concatenate them; I don't know how PHP does that.

Comment: Actually it does match the whole contents in a single call; that's what `preg_match_all()` does.  I was more concerned about PHP syntax, but I do believe `$match` does contain the same results as I've mentioned in my Ruby solution.

Comment: sorry for my poor english.

i mean one time is not only can run one time, that means need match more times and connect the result together. 

thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution won't work as '[' and ']' define a list of characters to match (or not)

One solution would be to just negate the match

```
$var !~ /%b\d+%/
```

This will match everything that doesn't contain %b1%, %b2%... etc